# If/else statement vs Heaviside function

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, if-statement, optimization

In my code I have to consider different contributions with respect to different thresholds. In particular I have a function `my_index` whose output must be compared to the thresholds `Z_1, Z_2, Z_3` in order to determine the increment to the variable `my_value`. In the following MWE, for simplicity sake, the function `my_index` is just a uniform random generator:

```
import numpy as np

my_len = 100000
Z_1 = 0.2
Z_2 = 0.4
Z_3 = 0.7

first = 1

second = 2

third = -0.0003

my_value = 0

for i in range(my_len):

  my_index = np.random.uniform()

  my_value += first*np.heaviside(my_index - Z_1,0)*np.heaviside(Z_2 - my_index,0) + second*np.heaviside(my_index - Z_3,0) + third*np.heaviside(Z_3 - my_index,0)

#if Z_1 < my_index < Z_2 add first
#if my_index > Z_3 add second
#if my_index < Z_3 add third
```

I have **replaced** `if/else`'s that could have been used for the thresholds with the Heaviside function [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Keep in mind that, in my original code, this code section has to be **iterated** up to 10^5 times.

**My question is**: does this practice make the code **faster**? Or is the heaviside function (`np.heaviside`) call *better* in terms of **speed** than the if/else control?

Comment: What did you find when you tested it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [433]: x=np.arange(-10,10)
In [434]: x
Out[434]: 
array([-10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2,
         3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9])
```

A proper use of `heaviside` - giving `x` as array, not a single value:

```
In [436]: np.heaviside(x,.5)
Out[436]: 
array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. , 1. ,
       1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ])
```

A list comprehension equivalent:

```
In [437]: [.5 if i==0 else (0 if i<0 else 1) for i in x]
Out[437]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and making an array from that list:

```
In [438]: np.array([.5 if i==0 else (0 if i<0 else 1) for i in x])
Out[438]: 
array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. , 1. ,
       1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ])
```

Compare the times:

```
In [439]: timeit np.heaviside(x,.5)
2.5 µs ± 17.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [440]: timeit np.array([.5 if i==0 else (0 if i<0 else 1) for i in x])
15.1 µs ± 25.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Iteration on a list is faster (than on an array):

```
In [441]: timeit np.array([.5 if i==0 else (0 if i<0 else 1) for i in x.tolist()])
6.66 µs ± 195 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and if we skip the conversion back to a list:

```
In [442]: timeit [.5 if i==0 else (0 if i<0 else 1) for i in x.tolist()]
2.28 µs ± 3.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For a much larger array, `heaviside` performance is even better:

```
In [445]: x=np.arange(-1000,1000)
In [446]: timeit [.5 if i==0 else (0 if i<0 else 1) for i in x.tolist()]
211 µs ± 7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [447]: timeit np.heaviside(x,.5)
13 µs ± 201 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

For the random number generation, taking the whole-array approach is also faster:

```
In [448]: timeit [np.random.uniform() for _ in range(1000)]
4.62 ms ± 20.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [449]: timeit np.random.uniform(1000)
4.74 µs ± 171 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I could also time the scalar use of `heaviside` - that is worse than the `if/else` in [446]:

```
In [450]: timeit [np.heaviside(i,.5) for i in x]
8.64 ms ± 44.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In sum:

- use whole-array code where possible
- when using Python level iteration, use lists and scalar methods instead

Comment: I notice that for large arrays heaviside works better. What about branchless programming?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the standard CPython **interpreter**, then performing a Numpy *function call* like `np.heaviside` is likely more expensive than doing basic conditionals. However, both are very inefficient. Indeed, conditionals are generally slow and could be replaced with a **branchless** implementation here (adding/multiplying booleans converted to integers). The most important optimization is to use **vectorization** because Numpy is design to be efficient on relatively big arrays and not scalar values (mainly due to additional internal checks and function calls). You can generate all the random value in a big array, apply the heaviside function on it multiple times. The resulting code will certainly be 2 or 3 order of magnitude faster!

Comment: This is a MWE in which I have considered the indicator just as a random var. My problem cannot be vectorized. However the real alternative is branchless programming. Could you  please provide an implementation of branchless progr on this MWE?